# serverless AWS deployment fails because of esbuild

Tags: serverless-framework

I'm using a Macbook M1 for development. When I try to deploy my serverless application to AWS I'm running into this error:

I'm using the aws-nodejs-typescript template.

```
You installed esbuild for another platform than the one you're currently using.
This won't work because esbuild is written with native code and needs to
install a platform-specific binary executable.

Specifically the "esbuild-darwin-arm64" package is present but this platform
needs the "esbuild-darwin-64" package instead. People often get into this
situation by installing esbuild with npm running inside of Rosetta 2 and then
trying to use it with node running outside of Rosetta 2, or vice versa (Rosetta
2 is Apple's on-the-fly x86_64-to-arm64 translation service).

If you are installing with npm, you can try ensuring that both npm and node are
not running under Rosetta 2 and then reinstalling esbuild. This likely involves
changing how you installed npm and/or node. For example, installing node with
the universal installer here should work: https://nodejs.org/en/download/. Or
you could consider using yarn instead of npm which has built-in support for
installing a package on multiple platforms simultaneously.

If you are installing with yarn, you can try listing both "arm64" and "x64"
in your ".yarnrc.yml" file using the "supportedArchitectures" feature:
https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc/#supportedArchitectures
Keep in mind that this means multiple copies of esbuild will be present.

Another alternative is to use the "esbuild-wasm" package instead, which works
the same way on all platforms. But it comes with a heavy performance cost and
can sometimes be 10x slower than the "esbuild" package, so you may also not
want to do that.
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: What type of installation did you choose for Serverless Framework? Are you using a standalone installation by any chance?

Comment: I'm using the serverless CLI, like: serverless create --template aws-nodejs-typescript

Comment: Sure, but how did you install the serverless CLI? With `npm` or some other way?

Comment: I don't remember tbh. But I think it was via npm

Answer (score 0):

I needed to reinstall serverlesss....

for that I deleted the folder ./serverless in the directory ~
and reinstalled using homebrew

https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/serverless#default

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).